# How to change settings to open an Rmd file without the default script in R?

Tags: r

Is there any way for me to open an Rmd file in R with just the yaml instead of everything else?

#### I'd like this...

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: ""
date: ""
output: html_document
---
```

---

#### Instead of ...

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: ""
date: ""
output: html_document
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
````

### Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

Comment: What is the objective of this? it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Bulat No particular reason, it's just a little annoying having to delete the code when you open a new rmd file.

Comment: Got it, it is annoying indeed. I understood what you want to achieve now )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have as far as I know two options:

#### 1. using {[rmarkdown::draft()](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/draft.html)}

You would need to save the template localy and create a new file withe the `draft()` function.

`draft(file, template, package = NULL, create_dir = "default", edit = TRUE)`

#### 2. create a package with the template and install the package.

You can copy and adapt [dr-harper's](https://github.com/dr-harper/example-rmd-templates) package with your custom templates and install the package locally. This option has the benefit of allowing you to choose the template from within RStudio's new-file interface.

To create the template, follow [Chapter 17 from R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html) of Yihui Xie, J. J. Allaire and Garrett Grolemund.

[image]